# My VBA Code to Auto FIlter Data will error out and freeze excel when Criteria Cell is blank

Tags: excel

I have a large data set with part numbers that I would like a VBA code wrote to Auto Filter when I enter the part number in a cell.  It works great, until I hit delete on the criteria cell, resulting in a Blank cell.  It will error and freeze excel. My Code is below, what can I add so when the criteria cell is blank, the autofilter will turn off.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
   If Target.Address = Range("J2").Address Then
       Range("A2:H50000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
   End If
End Sub
```

I've tried adding if statements and it errors.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updateby Extendoffice 20160606
   If Target.Address = Range("J2").Address Then
       Range("A2:H50000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
   End If
End Sub
```

What can I add so when the criteria cell is blank, the Auto-filter will turn off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Advanced Filter, not Auto Filter.

Does this help, just need to check if J2 contains anything

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$J$2" Then
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
        Range("A2:H50000").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2")
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked.  Now my next question, which I should have clarified better my apologies, when the cell is blank the data is still filtered on the previous criteria.  Can I have it return the data unfiltered when the cell is blank?

Comment: One question per, er, question please.

Comment: Actually you might just try `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` to refresh.